# pass intruction to form1 to form2 using radio buttons

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
if (RbAddition.Checked == true)
{
    frmExecute newFrm = new frmExecute();
    newFrm.Show();
}
else if (RbSubtration.Checked == true)
{
    frmExecute newFrm = new frmExecute();
    newFrm.Show();
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Choose");
}
```

i have radiobuttons in form1 Rbadd and Rbsubtract  and when i click radio button form2 pop up that do whatever the user
    check (if its addition or subtraction

Comment: So what is the problem? And there are so many questions about interaction between two winForm forms, sure non helped? Please show what you researched..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass aurgument to your constructeur of your form

```
if (RbAddition.Checked)
{
    frmExecute newFrm = new frmExecute("ADDITION");
    newFrm.ShowDialog();
}
else if (RbSubtration.Checked)
{
    frmExecute newFrm = new frmExecute("SUBSTRACTION");
    newFrm.ShowDialog();
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Choose");
}
```

Then you must create a constrcteur into you form frmExecute whith argument.

into frmExecute class:

```
   private string typeshow;

   public frmExecute(string typeshow)
   {
      this.typeshow= typeshow;
   }
```

Note: you should be use ShowDialog and not Show if you want only one Windows active